# How do I horizontally center a UIImageView in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, positioning

I am having trouble centering a 200x200 image horizontally inside a customized `UITableViewCell`. I have set the `tableViewheightForRowAtIndexPath` in the `UITableViewDelegate` to the appropriate value, but that doesn't center my image horizontally, it does so only vertically (better than nothing I guess). I also tried to change the value of the `imageView.frame` in `layoutSubviews` in my customized cell, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I have even commented it out, placed it before `[super layoutSubviews];`, played around with the values of the frame, but I keep getting the same result.

Can anyone help me with this? What code should I write to achieve such an effect?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a nib to make your customized UITableViewCell? If not, this is very easy to accomplish using a nib.

Comment: No nibs whatsoever. I am doing everything programmatically, because I need to do things dynamically. Any ideas? If not, could you tell me how to do it in IB, then I might know what's causing this. Thanks

Comment: In IB, you need only put the UIImageView in the centre of the cell, and then it will always be displayed there. If you want to do it programatically, maybe play with the bounds?

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer. I had to play with the bounds of the contentView, not the imageView. I changed the values of the bounds and frame of imageView so many times, but I guess it's the contentView that should be changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will try this code its help you

You need to subclass UITableViewCell and override layoutSubviews, as follows:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{   
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 10, 10, 50, 50 ); // your positioning here
}
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, be sure to return an instance of your new cell type.

Comment: This worked! I was trying to change the frame of a UIImageView that I added, and that was why it wasn't working. I also found that changing the bounds of the contentView achieves the same effect, but I guess that's because I have the only one element: the image. Thanks.

Comment: Worked very well. Gonna make a little step-by-step tutorial and post the link here, cos this issue annoyed me very much

Answer (score 0):

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 UIImageView *imgView; 
 if(cell == nil)
 {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

   imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(100,0,100,62)];
    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
    imgView.tag = 55;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];
 } 
 else
 {
        imgView = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:55];
 }
```